# createBrowserhistory from history npm Url changes but not component React-redux

Tags: react-redux, react-router-dom, react-thunk

Having same version for **react** and **react-dom**
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0" and history is latest
"history": "^5.3.0",

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import SignInSide from "./components/mui/signIn/SignInSide";
import store from "./Store/Store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import Dashboard from "./components/mui/Dashboard";
import history from './utils/history';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<SignInSide />} />
          <Route path="/home" element={<Dashboard />} >
          </Route>
          <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);


 function SignInSide(props) {
          const handleSubmit = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const form = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
            let user = {
              email: form.get('email'),
              password: form.get('password')
            }
            console.log(user);
            props.signIn(user);
          };
    
      return (....);
```

Calling handleSubmit from singIn button

```
 import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export function LoginUser(LogInData) {
  let navigate = useNavigate;
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(AuthActions.userSignIn());
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, LogInData.email, LogInData.password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        dispatch(AuthActions.userSignInSuccess(user));
        setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence)
          .then(() => {
            return signInWithEmailAndPassword(
              auth,
              LogInData.email,
              LogInData.password
            );
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            // Handle Errors here.
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
          });
        history.push("/home");
        // console.log(store);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        dispatch(AuthActions.userSignInFailed(error));
      });
  };
}
```

> Using history.push("/home") this only Url replaced not component loading so please provide the solution with using latest npm version(if any) or suggest ready template ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

The `react-router-dom@6` `BrowserRouter` doesn't take a `history` prop.

[BrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/routers/browser-router)

> ```
> declare function BrowserRouter(
>   props: BrowserRouterProps
> ): React.ReactElement;
>
> interface BrowserRouterProps {
>   basename?: string;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   window?: Window;
> }
> ```

If you want to use a custom `history` object then you should import the [HistoryRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/routers/history-router) and pass the `history` prop for the type of history object you are creating for your app.

HistoryRouter

> ```
> declare function HistoryRouter(
>   props: HistoryRouterProps
> ): React.ReactElement;
>
> interface HistoryRouterProps {
>   basename?: string;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   history: History;
> }
> ```

Ensure that your entire app is importing and referencing the same single `history` object instance that is passed to the router.

Create the history object

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default history;
```

Import the `HistoryRouter` and the custom `history` object.

```
...
import { HistoryRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
...
import history from './utils/history';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<SignInSide />} />
          <Route path="/home" element={<Dashboard />} >
          </Route>
          <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

...

```
import history from './utils/history';

export function loginUser(logInData) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(AuthActions.userSignIn());
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, logInData.email, logInData.password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        dispatch(AuthActions.userSignInSuccess(user));

        setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence)
          .then(() => {
            return signInWithEmailAndPassword(
              auth,
              logInData.email,
              logInData.password
            );
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            // Handle Errors here.
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
          });

        history.push("/home");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        dispatch(AuthActions.userSignInFailed(error));
      });
  };
}
```